# Is argLine propagated to children modules from parent pom.xml?

Tags: maven

I know that generally properties of parent `pom.xml` are propagated to children one. But there is one doubt regarding [`argLine` property](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine).
If I have a parent `pom.xml` with declared `argLine` and some children modules, say:

```
<properties>    
   <argLine>-Xmx...M</argLine>
</properties>

<modules>
   <module>child1</module>
   <module>child2</module>
   ...
</modules>
```

Will these arguments be reused by children modules surfire plugin?

Comment: I would suggest to use a pluginManagement for surefire plugin and define the args line in the configuration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is propagated as well as all other properties. It can be easily checked (and this is what I actually did).